# Active Directory Name Change

Tags: sql-server, security, windows-server, authentication, logins

Our Active directory will change the accounts name for example John Doe Jdoe@abcd.com to John.Doe@abcd.com.

My question is do I need to change all the SQL Logins individually or the person can login to SQL server management studio with their old names. What also happens if the login is an owner of a database or job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server stores Active Directory accounts using a unique identifier generated by Active Directory.  The unique identifier is generated when the object is created in Active Directory, and never changes.

This means you can change things like the user name, first name, last name, and any other Active Directory attribute for the user, without the need to even touch SQL Server or SSMS in any way.

In other words, you can change their account name in AD, and not worry about SQL Server at all.

Comment: So I did a test and i found that everything works after change without having to change anything on the sql server and in fact the logins also got changed on the sql server and only SSMS was showing the old name and once the server got restarted showed the new name. Another important feature learned. Thank you @Max Vernon